# How to play a simulated signal continuously with QAudioOutput?

Tags: qt, c++11

I have written a c++ code in Qt to generate an Engine Sound Signal at a sampling frequency of `16384` every second. So my timer is running every second
and I am getting a new Vector of size `16384` every second.
I am trying to play this signal using `QAudioOutput`. I am getting audio output every second but not a continuous sound.

```
    qreal sampleRate = 16384; 
        qreal duration = 1.000;
        qreal frequency = 1000;




// --- generate a QVector<double> xengine that contains a 16384 samples of data ---


// --- transfer QVector data to QByteArray 
        QByteArray* byteBuffer = new QByteArray();
        int n = xengine.size();
        byteBuffer->resize(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < xengine.size(); i++)
        {
            qreal y = xengine[i];   // transfer data to y
            *byteBuffer)[i] = (qint16)y;  enter code here
        } 



// use qint16 (instead of quint16), because our waveform goes above and below zeros.


   // create and setup a QAudioFormat object
        QAudioFormat audioFormat;
        audioFormat.setSampleRate(static_cast<int>(sampleRate));
        audioFormat.setChannelCount(1);
        audioFormat.setSampleSize(8);   
        audioFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm");
        audioFormat.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
        audioFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);   


   // create a QAudioDeviceInfo object, to make sure that our audioFormat is supported by the device

         QAudioDeviceInfo deviceInfo(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());

         if(!deviceInfo.isFormatSupported(audioFormat))
         {
              qWarning() << "Raw audio format not supported by backend, 
              cannot play audio.";
             return;
         }


         QBuffer* input = new QBuffer(byteBuffer);
         input->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);   
         QAudioOutput* audio = new QAudioOutput(audioFormat, this);


         audio->start(input);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pull mode, the audio data is read until the end of the buffer, you can restart and play the buffer again, but this can generate an moment of silence between the final of the old audio and the audio restart.

Instead i suggest you use push mode, where you have more control of the audio reproduction.

Please see the following example:

**EDIT:** This answer was edited to show a way to add data on demand to reproduce, if you have your sound generator, ignore the tone generator provided here and replace it with your generator.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtMultimedia>

static inline int timeToSize(int ms, const QAudioFormat &format)
{
    return ((format.channelCount() * (format.sampleSize() / 8) * format.sampleRate()) * ms / 1000);
}

struct AudioContext
{
    QAudioOutput *m_audio_output;
    QIODevice *m_output_device;

    QByteArray m_buffer;

    QAudioDeviceInfo m_output_device_info;
    QAudioFormat m_format;

    int m_time_to_buffer;

    int m_size_to_buffer;

    /*** Tone generator variables ***/
    uint m_frequency;

    uint m_duration_msecs;

    bool m_reverse = false;
    /*** Tone generator variables ***/

    bool m_play_called = false;
};

QByteArray toneGenerator(AudioContext *ctx)
{
    QByteArray data;

    QDataStream write_stream(&data, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    write_stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0); //Protocol for version 5.0
    write_stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

    //Tone generator from http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/129827/

    const uint samplerate = uint(ctx->m_format.sampleRate());
    const uint channels = uint(ctx->m_format.channelCount());

    const double pi = M_PI;
    const qint16 amplitude = INT16_MAX;

    const uint frequency = ctx->m_frequency;
    const uint n_msecs = ctx->m_duration_msecs;

    const int n_samples = int(channels * samplerate * (n_msecs / double(1000)));

    int index = n_samples;

    double freq = frequency;
    double d = (samplerate / freq);
    int c = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < index; j++)
    {
        double deg = double(360) / d;
        write_stream << qint16(qSin((c++ * double(deg)) * pi / double(180)) * amplitude);
    }

    return data;
}

void play(AudioContext *ctx)
{
    //Set that last async call was triggered
    ctx->m_play_called = false;

    while (ctx->m_buffer.size() < ctx->m_size_to_buffer)
    {
        QByteArray data = toneGenerator(ctx);

        //APPEND HERE YOUR DATA
        ctx->m_buffer.append(data);

        if (!ctx->m_reverse)
        {
            if (ctx->m_frequency < 20 * 1000)
                ctx->m_frequency += 100;
            else //Restart
                ctx->m_reverse = !ctx->m_reverse;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ctx->m_frequency > 100)
                ctx->m_frequency -= 100;
            else //Restart
                ctx->m_reverse = !ctx->m_reverse;
        }
    }

    int readlen = ctx->m_audio_output->periodSize();

    int chunks = ctx->m_audio_output->bytesFree() / readlen;

    //Play data while it's available in the output device
    while (chunks)
    {
        //Get chunk from the buffer
        QByteArray samples = ctx->m_buffer.mid(0, readlen);
        int len = samples.size();
        ctx->m_buffer.remove(0, len);

        //Write data to the output device after the volume was applied
        if (len)
        {
            ctx->m_output_device->write(samples);
        }

        //If chunk is smaller than the output chunk size, exit loop
        if (len != readlen)
            break;

        //Decrease the available number of chunks
        chunks--;
    }
}

void preplay(AudioContext *ctx)
{
    //Verify if exists a pending call to play function
    //If not, call the play function async
    if (!ctx->m_play_called)
    {
        ctx->m_play_called = true;
        QTimer::singleShot(0, [=]{play(ctx);});
    }
}

void init(AudioContext *ctx)
{
    /***** INITIALIZE OUTPUT *****/

    //Check if format is supported by the choosen output device
    if (!ctx->m_output_device_info.isFormatSupported(ctx->m_format))
    {
        qDebug() << "Format not supported by the output device";
        return;
    }

    //Initialize the audio output device
    ctx->m_audio_output = new QAudioOutput(ctx->m_output_device_info, ctx->m_format, qApp);

    //Compute the size in bytes to be buffered based on the current format
    ctx->m_size_to_buffer = int(timeToSize(ctx->m_time_to_buffer, ctx->m_format));

    ctx->m_output_device = ctx->m_audio_output->start();

    if (!ctx->m_output_device)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open output audio device";
        return;
    }

    //Timer that helps to keep playing data while it's available on the internal buffer
    QTimer *timer_play = new QTimer(qApp);
    timer_play->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
    QObject::connect(timer_play, &QTimer::timeout, [=]{
        preplay(ctx);
    });
    timer_play->start(10);

    /***** INITIALIZE OUTPUT *****/

    qDebug() << "Playing...";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    AudioContext ctx;

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);

    ctx.m_format = format;

    ctx.m_output_device_info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice();

    ctx.m_time_to_buffer = 1000; //Needed time in buffer before play(ms)

    ctx.m_duration_msecs = 20; //Duration of each tone(ms)

    ctx.m_frequency = 100; //Initial tone frequency(hz)

    init(&ctx);

    return a.exec();
}
```

For more information about pull and push modes, see:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html

Comment: I am getting "Format not supported by the output device" error when tried this approach.

Comment: I changed the sample rate to 8000 hz, there is more chances of success with that configuration.

Comment: It is working now,But in this example the toneGenerator method is being called once and after that the same tone is being played continuously.In my problem the data is changing every second and i have to  play changing data.

Comment: Thank's,It worked. Every time the buffer is running out of data ,i  am feeding it with new data from my own function.